# How can I put white spaces in Title of QGroundControl?

Tags: c++, qml, qt-creator, qgroundcontrol

Is there a way that I put the white spaces in the QGroundControl? I am new to this and not sure much about QML or qmake.

I want to change title from “QGroundControl” to “Q Ground Control”.
I tried to do the change in the **“qgroundcontrol.pro”** at the below line, but this didn’t worked as I was expecting.

**FROM:** `DEFINES += QGC_APPLICATION_NAME=\"\\\"QGroundControl\\\"\"`

**TO:** `DEFINES += QGC_APPLICATION_NAME=\"\\\"Q Ground Control\\\"\"`

**The RESULT is:** Q -DGround -DControl

**Required Result:** Q Ground Control

Comment: It works for me, in Qt Creator 4.9.2. (Except that I have `DEFINES += QGC_APPLICATION_NAME="\"Q Ground Control\""` instead of `DEFINES += QGC_APPLICATION_NAME="\“Q Ground Control\”"` -- look carefully at those quotation marks!)

Comment: @TonyK I am using Qt Creator 4.10.2  --  Based on Qt 5.13.2 (MSVC 2017, 32bit).

Comment: @TonyK : Sorry I gave the incorrect code. I just updated with the correct one in my original question. I tired the one you gave, that didn't worked either. Got a couple of compile time errors.

Comment: I am using the g++ compiler, not MSVC. Perhaps that is what makes the difference. What is the compiler command line (in the Compile Output window)?

Comment: @TonyK Any suggestions with my problem in case of MSVC?

Comment: @TonyK : **Here is the output of Compile Output Window:**  
jom: D:\build-qgroundcontrol-Desktop_Qt_5_12_6_MSVC2017_64bit-Debug\Makefile [release\QGroundControl.exe] Error 1
23:55:40: The process "F:\Qt\Qt5.12.6\Tools\QtCreator\bin\jom.exe" exited with code 2.
Error while building/deploying project qgroundcontrol (kit: Desktop Qt 5.12.6 MSVC2017 64bit)
The kit Desktop Qt 5.12.6 MSVC2017 64bit has configuration issues which might be the root cause for this problem.
When executing step "Make"

Comment: Don't you have a _compiler command line_ to show us from the Compile Output window?

Comment: @TonyK : I didn't found the _compiler command line_ in the **Compile Output Window**. But here is the complete output of the Compile Output Window after building the complete project. ----> https://file.io/74tVR4Vs

Comment: file.io 404 Page not found. (Also, you said that you tried my suggestion, and you got "a couple of compile time errors". So you _do_ have a compiler command line for that experiment?)

Comment: sorry for broken link, here is the _new link_ of log file:  https://drive.google.com/file/d/1AIZZ6uy6VaDbZL-L_ITlJESednTQcKNs/view?usp=sharing  Actually I am not getting anything about Compiler command line, can you please help me with a snapshot or something useful!

Comment: Every command that starts with `cl -c` is a compiler command line. There are hundreds of them in that huge file.

Comment: Yes, there are so many lines which starts with **cl -c**. Any other way to get around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed my issue by using the correct escape sequence:

```
DEFINES += QGC_APPLICATION_NAME='"\\\"Custom QGroundControl\\\""'
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, I think I have a solution for you:

```
QGC = '\\"Q Ground Control\\"'
DEFINES += QGC_APPLICATION_NAME=\"$${QGC}\"
```

Try it and let us know how it goes.

Comment: I really appreciate your efforts in doing help. But my problem is fixed using the following escape sequence which I got from another source: DEFINES += QGC_APPLICATION_NAME='"\\\"Custom QGroundControl\\\""'